# Ldap exchange group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I just want to ask you what is exactly exchange group in LDAP (if I use correctly the term and if the term exists) and how to query to get only exchange groups using ldap?
The client emphasize on it so I need to understand it and to know how to retrieve it.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about the Active Directory LDAP, correct?

A group in AD can be either distribution (i.e. exchange-only) or security.

Also, a group can be one of the 3 scopes: Universal, Global and Domain local. [Here's the doc with the differences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). A universal security groups [can be mail-enabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123805.aspx), to act as a distribution group.

To query for all mail-enabled groups in a domain/container regardless of the group type, you can search for `(&(objectClass=group)(proxyAddresses=*))`